# Why first maven launch in a docker container is so long

Tags: docker, maven

i have something i can't explain...
Does somebody have an idea ?

[image]

Comment: J9 preprocesses classes. Try hotspot.

Comment: OK but why only on the first docker run ?
I remove the docker cache and then run a new container without the problem ...

Comment: After trying hotspot or eclipse adoptium jdk, there is no first time overhead !
Thks @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: Can be your antivirus too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897/thorbj%c3%b8rn-ravn-andersen) who posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73025248/why-first-maven-launch-in-a-docker-container-is-so-long/73036513#comment128979034_73025248):

> J9 preprocesses classes. Try hotspot.

I switched to hotspot versions and there is no overhead.